# Summary Statistics for string types in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there something like summary function in spark like that in "R".

The summary calculation which comes with spark(MultivariateStatisticalSummary) operates only on numeric types.

I am interested in getting the results for string types also like the first four max occuring strings(groupby kind of operation) , number of uniques etc.

Is there any preexisting code for this ?

If not what please suggest the best way to deal with string types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a thing for String in MLlib. But it would probably be a valuable contribution, if you are going to implement it.

Calculating just one of these metrics is easy. E.g. for top 4 by frequency:

```
def top4(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]) =
  rdd
    .map(s => (s, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map { case (s, count) => (count, s) }
    .top(4)
    .map { case (count, s) => s }
```

Or number of uniques:

```
def numUnique(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]) =
  rdd.distinct.count
```

But doing this for all metrics in a single pass takes more work.

---

These examples assume that, if you have multiple "columns" of data, you have split each column into a separate RDD. This is a good way to organize the data, and it's necessary for operations that perform a shuffle.

What I mean by splitting up the columns:

```
def split(together: RDD[(Long, Seq[String])],
          columns: Int): Seq[RDD[(Long, String)]] = {
  together.cache // We will do N passes over this RDD.
  (0 until columns).map {
    i => together.mapValues(s => s(i))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel...but I am trying to do this operation for every column in the dataset which can consist of string/numeric types.

Comment: The same applies if you have one RDD per column. If you have all the columns in one RDD then I would recommend splitting it up :).

Comment: Can you please provide some reference on how to split a RDD columnwise. Thanks.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include what I had in mind. Does that make sense?